# Can i be hosting on a dedicated server and serve only my homepage from Amazon S3?

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I currently host on a dedicated server. I want to serve only my homepage from Amazon S3/CDN. Is this in anyway possible using DNS.

Only Homepage should be served using amazon s3/cdn, rest of the pages should be served from the dedicated server.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What would be the reason for such a construct?

Comment: homepage is the main page of the site, you want it to load as fast as possible and this will also support gzip without any extra overhead, homepage could take any amount of traffic and would load from nearest cdn location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple to do this with DNS. Host your home page (e.g. www.example.com) on Amazon S3, and use a different hostname for the remainder of your site, (e.g. www2.example.com - replace `www2` with whatever suits you best). You'll have to change all the links on your homepage to point to `www2`.

Simply point the a-record for `www` to your Amazon S3 IP, and the `www2` record to the other web server.

Comment: The solution is good, but changing other links to www2 is impossible as its a huge content site and would also affect seo in some way. if i think otherwise like having www2 for homepage -- then it also affect as people tend to type www prefix more. Any other solution?